# CameraPosition doesn't work well with setPadding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

1. Setup a fullscreen map
2. Set some padding e.g: `map.setPadding(0, 200, 0, 0)`
3. Tilt + rotate the map, as a user would
4. Try to reset the tilt/rotation using CameraPosition like that:

   ```
   CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
           .target(userLatLng)
           .zoom(zoomLevel)
           .tilt(0)
           .bearing(0)
           .build();
   CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
   map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate, mapAnimationCallback);
   ```

You will see that we map has 0 tilt and 0 bearing but the target will not be the same as `userLatLng`. It will always have some offset.

If you have no map padding (`map.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)`) the whole animation works fine.

Any idea why this is happening/ how to make a proper animation with `tilt/bearing` while having padding?

Answer (score 2):

It's a still open bug since  Oct 3, 2013.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5881&q=padding&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

It also looks like uneven padding is the root cause. I.e. `map.setPadding(0, 200, 0, 200)` will give you a correct animation.